# Calculating Quarterly Returns using Daily Prices in R

Tags: programming, returns, quantmod

I am trying to compute quarterly returns with daily stock prices. However, I don't want to use the quantmod function "quarterlyReturn(x)" for each single stock but instead for the whole list of stocks...

I would be happy about any advice on how to get there.

The beginning looks like this:

```
 TickerList <- c("SPG", "AKR","AIV", "ARE", "AAT", "AMT", "ARI", "ABR", "ARR" )

 ClosingPricesRead <- NULL for (Ticker in TickerList)  ClosingPricesRead <- cbind(ClosingPricesRead,
                  getSymbols(Ticker, from="1950-01-01", >verbose=FALSE, auto.assign=FALSE)[,6]) 

    ClosingPrices <- ClosingPricesRead[apply(ClosingPricesRead,1,function(x)
                     all(!is.na(x))),]
```

Now I would like to convert my daily closing Prices to quarterly returns, in such a way that I get a new dataframe with the returns for all Stocks. 
 I tried to use the quantmod package so that:

```
apply(ClosingPrices, 2, function(x),quarterlyReturn(x))
```

But I am just receiving error messages...

Since I am fairly new to R, I would really appreciate your help!

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and the error messages you're receiving.

Comment: @BobJansen thanks for your prompt response! Next time I will include a reproducible example, thx for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the answer is quite simple!

I just needed to adjust the "lapply" function correctly such that:

```
QuarterlyReturns <- lapply(Prices, quarterlyReturn, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

Now the calculation works perfectly fine.